# Why distinguish between polarity and hydrophobicity?

Tags: water, polarity

I have yet to see an example of a molecule that's both polar and hydrophobic or that's both non-polar an hydrophilic. If no such molecule exists, why use the terms "hydrophilic" and "hydrophobic" at all if we can just refer to them as being polar or non-polar? If there are such molecules, what are some examples and why do they exhibit non-polarity and hydrophilicty, or polarity and hydrophobicity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hydrophilicity/hydrophobicity/lipophilicity/lipophobicity and polarity/non-polarity are terms that overlap to a great extent in simple substances, but which are not strictly equal. The former terms can have a much more involved explanation depending on several factors, even if polarity is usually the largest by far.

Philicity and phobicity are determined by [contact angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_angle) between substances. It is possible to vary how a same substance gets wetted by exploiting [surface patterning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aMicrostruct_superhydrophobic.png), which fiddles with the surface tension between the substances in contact.

Another interesting example I can think of is that some large [perfluorocarbons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorocarbon) are non-polar, but they are *also* lipophobic. It is possible to mix water, oil and a perfluorinated solvent, shake, and then watch as three clearly distinct phases separate.

Comment: So if I understand you right, a molecule's polarity can be a contributing explanation for its observed hydrophobicity, but saying the reverse (hydrophobicity explaining polarity) wouldn't make much sense. I'll have to check out those wikipedia pages as well.